# Using response.follow in XMLFeedSpider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, xml-parsing

I am writing XMLFeedSpider (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.4/topics/spiders.html#xmlfeedspider), which needs to parse additional information from an url in the items. But when I yield a `response.follow` in `parse_node`, the next node will not be parsed / only the first node and one `response.follow` request will be parsed. The response follow somehow disrupts the iteration in `parse_nodes`. Any ideas how to solve this?

### The code in general

shortened and cleaned

```
class example_domainSpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = 'example_domain'
    allowed_domains = ['example_domain.org']
    start_urls = ['https://items.example_domain.org/some-api']
    iterator = 'iternodes'
    itertag = 'Some_Item'

    Item = None

    def parse_node(self, response, selector):

        xml_data = dict()

        # a lot of selectors to fill xml_data
        # pass data to next method, so it can be combined in one item
        return response.follow(link, self.parse_item, meta={'xml_data': xml_data})

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.Item = item()

        xml_data = response.request.meta['xml_data']
        # fill item with the data from xml
        for key, value in xml_data.items():
            self.Item[key] = value

    # a lot of selectors to fill self.Item

        yield self.Item
```

Comment: Does it change if you use `yield` instead of `return` for `response.follow`? Does `parse_node` get called more than once if you don’t use `response.follow`, as you seem to suggest?

Comment: No, ```yield``` and ```return``` results in the same problem.

Yes, ```parse_node``` gets called for every node, if I yield an ```Item()``` or ```dict()```.